# Building wxWidgets using Cmake in a subdirectory

Tags: c++, cmake, wxwidgets

I'm trying to build a project with cmake that includes wxWidgets as a subdirectory similar to the last section in:

- https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_cmake.html

The project has the following structure:

```
.
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── Doxyfile
├── include
│   ├── gui
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   └── ui.hpp
│   ├── main.hpp
│   └── processor
│       └── toy_processor.hpp
├── libs
│   └── wxWidgets-3.1.6
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── gui
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   └── ui.cpp
    ├── main.cpp
    └── processor
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        └── toy_processor.cpp
```

and my CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(ToyV2)

include_directories(include/ libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/)
add_subdirectory(src/gui/)
add_subdirectory(include/gui/)
add_subdirectory(src/processor/)
add_subdirectory(libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/)

add_executable(ToyV2 src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ToyV2 gui)
target_link_libraries(ToyV2 processor)
target_link_libraries(ToyV2 wx::net wx::core wx::base)
```

But every time I build the project there seem to be a whole lot of contradicting declarations, here's a snippet:

```
[ 14%] Built target wxbase
[ 55%] Built target wxcore
Scanning dependencies of target gui
[ 55%] Building CXX object src/gui/CMakeFiles/gui.dir/ui.cpp.o
In file included from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/defs.h:933,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/event.h:14,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/window.h:18,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/nonownedwnd.h:14,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/toplevel.h:20,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/frame.h:18,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/include/gui/ui.hpp:14,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/src/gui/ui.cpp:1:
/home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/types.h:161:30: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
  161 |         wxCOMPILE_TIME_ASSERT( sizeof(int) == 4, IntMustBeExactly4Bytes);
      |                              ^
/home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/types.h:162:30: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
  162 |         wxCOMPILE_TIME_ASSERT( sizeof(size_t) == 4, SizeTMustBeExactly4Bytes);
      |                              ^
/home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/types.h:163:30: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
  163 |         wxCOMPILE_TIME_ASSERT( sizeof(void *) == 4, PtrMustBeExactly4Bytes);
      |                              ^
/home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/types.h:180:34: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
  180 |             wxCOMPILE_TIME_ASSERT( sizeof(wchar_t) == 2,
      |                                  ^
In file included from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/string.h:31,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/memory.h:15,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/object.h:19,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/event.h:16,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/window.h:18,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/nonownedwnd.h:14,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/toplevel.h:20,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/frame.h:18,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/include/gui/ui.hpp:14,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/src/gui/ui.cpp:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:77:19: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef __ssize_t ssize_t’
   77 | typedef __ssize_t ssize_t;
      |                   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/defs.h:933,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/event.h:14,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/window.h:18,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/nonownedwnd.h:14,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/toplevel.h:20,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/frame.h:18,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/include/gui/ui.hpp:14,
                 from /home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/src/gui/ui.cpp:1:
/home/benedict/projects/toy-processor-2/libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/wx/types.h:332:25: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef wxInt32 ssize_t’
  332 |         typedef wxInt32 ssize_t;
      |                         ^~~~~~~
```

Any ideas what I’m doing wrong here?

Comment: The call `include_directories()` with parameter `libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6/include/` smells a lot when used before building `libs/wxWidgets-3.1.6` project: the project should be able to find its own headers without hints from outside.

Comment: Have you tried to build wxWidgets **standalone**? This step could help a lot when debug problems with building it as a *subproject*. If standalone build fails (with the same error), then it is simpler to debug exactly standalone build. If standalone build succeed, then the problem is directly related with the way how you build the subproject.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried building it on its own and that worked without problems.
Sadly, calling include_directories after building the project didn't change much.